# Backbone JS - Set model attribute node object with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So the title is a little confusing, I think, but here's the issue:

I have one model for my entire page called FD.page.  I have an attribute of that model called filters, thus FD.page.get("filters") returns an object with multiple attributes itself, date, location, etc.

I would like to be able to set values to the attributes of the filters attribute, and I can't seem to figure out how to specify that node.

So something like FD.page.set("filters.location", "close");

Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `filters` a backbone model

`FD.page.get('filters').set('location', 'close');`

Will fire change event.

Comment: That's it.  Sweet.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `FD.page.get('filters')['location'] = 'close';`

This won't fire a change event on the model though. If you want to fire the change event, then you'll have to fire it manually after you set it.